# Migrating from glassfish to tomee+

Tags: glassfish, apache-tomee

I have an application which runs on Glassfish 3.1.2, but now i want to migrate to Tomee+. I
have created connection pool in Glassfish and have configured that pool with JNDI, and used 
that JNDI Name in persistence.xml. Now while migration **how should i create connection pool 
and JNDI (and also where) in tomee+**, so that i can use JNDI name in my persistence.xml.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe http://tomee.apache.org/configuring-datasources.html is the place to look. Basically just declare the Datasource in tomee.xml.

Side note: WEB-INF/resources.xml has alsmot the same syntax and allows to embed the datasource in the war when you can't configure the container (cloud)